# Print multiple bash variables

Tags: bash, indirection

I have the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
d5=me
d6=you
d7=re

for i in {5..7}
do
    echo $"d$i"
 done
```

This prints out 
d5 
d6 
d7

I'm looking to print 
me 
you 
re

Comment: Why don't you use an array? Any time you find yourself constructing variables with sequential names like that, it probably should be an array instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `"${!varName}"` to reference value stored in `varName` variable:

```
for i in {5..7}; do v="d$i"; echo "${!v}"; done
me
you
re
```

[Check indirect variable expansion in bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html)

Or even simpler:

```
for v in d{5..7}; do echo "${!v}"; done
me
you
re
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `eval`:

```
for i in {5..7}; do eval echo \$d$i ; done
```

Comment: Yes, you _could_ use `eval`, but given that there's a dedicated mechanism for indirect variable expansion (see anubhava's answer), why _would_ you, given `eval`'s security risks?